# React router regexp path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this route. I need this route to work always except `/category`.

I'll get the path `/categories/id`

```
<Route key='breadcrumbs' path='((?!category).)*' component={BreadcrumbsComponent} />
```

Comment: You can define `<Route path="/category" exact component={NotFound} />` as the first element in your router. So when '/category' gets hit the component that will show is `NotFound`

Comment: This route for my BreadcrumbsComponent, and in other component I need /category/.... path.

Comment: Need more info on your question as to why you are doing it

Comment: I need exept path='/category' from route  <Route key='breadcrumbs' path=':path' component={BreadcrumbsComponent} />. How can I do this.